# Android Gradle Plugin (Warning) API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'

Tags: android, gradle, plugins, arcore, variant

I am trying to build and run this repository [augmented-images](https://github.com/Ayusch/augmented-images)
and I encounted this error.

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating sfa.

Which drill down to this warning Warning ! API `'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'`.

More from the build log analysis I see the following errors
ERROR: Failed to import 'sampledata/airplane/Airplane.obj'

I tried to find where this

```
variant.getMergeResources()
```

is used so I can replace it but no luck.

Please assist maybe I need to update the plugin. Which steps should I follow that is what I suspect will be the solution.

Answer (score 12):

Changing `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` works for now..

Comment: this is working for me but i need alternative permanent answer.

Comment: This warning is caused by the latest version of google services, they will fix in the future versions, so currently no permanent solution..

Comment: This works but then the build throws OutOfMemoryError

Answer (score 0):

Now **it is fixed** with the [release](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2019-09-06) `'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'`

This issue is caused by the versions of the [Google Services pluigin for gradle](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) `4.3.0` and `4.3.1`.