# How to fix variant.getMergeResources()

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, build.gradle

when I put **`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`** it show this error

> WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.

When I Use lower Version of google service or If I remove google plugin, this error doesn't show. But other feature not working properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Gradle Plugin (Warning) API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878137/android-gradle-plugin-warning-api-variant-getmergeresources-is-obsolete-an)

Answer (score 0):

There is no permanent solution as of now, as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56848644/11016588) referenced by Shashanth in the comments states,

> Changing `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` works for now

On the other hand, if you're asking this since you're working with `Sceneform` and Firebase is unable to be configured. Then this is an [open issue](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/408), with the following 'potential fix'.

> You can switch off Sceneform plugin, sync and try to connect to Firebase again - must be success now.
>
> After successful connection to Firebase you can return your plugin and resync. Warning will appear again, but it is not important, because Firebase has configured already.

P.S - This is probably an issue in the google services, which they'll fix in the future versions, so as long as it doesn't break anything, you shouldn't really need to worry.